# What do you call it when an animal uses its claws, but not to kill or maul but rather to fend off what it perceives as a threat?

Tags: word-request

What do you call it when, for example, a cat uses its claws so that it may, but not necessarily does, inflict a minor injury, like a scratch? For example, a domestic cat may do this rapid defensive movement with its paws if some unfamiliar human tries to take or pet it. What verb(s) could be used?

> Don't come too close, it may __________ you!

Comment: The word is **scratch**.  *Swipe* does not work here.

Comment: Not take. Pick it up.

Comment: You have asked for a word that means that cat may or may not scratch you but then you included **may** in the sentence asking for the word. If you include **may**, as you have, then scratch meets the definition. Without the word **may**, I would say *Don't come too close; she scratches people.*

Comment: The only two ways a cat can inflict a wound is by biting or scratching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the word you want is "swipe"

> to hit or try to hit something, especially with a sideways movement:  (Cambridge)

> The cat swiped at my hand when I bent down to pet it.

or as a noun

> Don't come too close, it may take a swipe at you!

Comment: And if a cat manages to make a cut, you would call it simply "scratch", wouldn't you? "Don't come too close, it may ____ you"

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I would never use "swipe" in this sense without "at" - "it may take a swipe **at** you!"

Comment: yes ... typo....

Comment: No, not *swipe*.  When was the last time you were *swiped* by something and what was the immediate effect?  A cat may swipe at you with its paw but if its claws are withdrawn it will merely tickle and could result in the cuddling of said cat.

Comment: People cuddle cats, not the other way round. That said, not all swiping results in claws scratching the skin. That is the point.

Comment: @Lambie - You know nothing about cats. I bet they bite you when you try to pick them up. Cuddling **of** cat means you cuddle cat.  Cuddling **by** cat means cat cuddles you.  Hone those skills.  You seem to be a bit rusty.

Comment: @EllieK You have shown up here recently making certain remarks that are quite aggressive. Be that as it may, you are no native speaker. Cats do not cuddle people. "Cuddling by cat" is incorrect English. We'd say (though it is impossible): cuddling by **a** cat. Apparently, you learned the phrase: hone one's skills and keep repeating it like some sort of mantra. Tsk, tsk, tsk.

Comment: And apparently, you didn't read that I said the cat was from a shelter and not ready to be picked up. I am probably twice your age and have had more cats than one can shake a stick at (skill honing). Your comment is very childish. Cats snuggle up to people they do not cuddle them. Cuddling is done with arms.

Answer (score -1):

I was actually bitten by a **cat who was not ready to be picked up. It was a rescue.**

It bit my hand and it scratched it.

My hand blew up like a pumpkin and I was on antibiotics for two weeks.

It was not the cat's fault, it was mine. Stupid human. :)

The cat was fending me off. Scratching and biting is all they can do to fend off a threat.

Comment: I don't think this attempts to answer the question.  But I hope your hand got better.

Comment: Of course it does: cats scratch with their claws. And swiping does not mean they actually made contact.

Comment: Dveers: tsk, tsk, tsk